# Can we hot deploy *.xml files by using JREBEL?

Tags: jrebel

Can we hot deploy *.xml files by using JREBEL?

In out project most of work is done through XML and we are planning to use JREBEL for the same.

Answer (score 0):

**The short answer:**

Yes, you can.

**The long answer:**

It actually depends on the nature of those XML files, what your application is doing with those files. Are those the configuration files which might be used in order to populate some application specific structures? If so, then those internal structures have to be reinitialized. This is possible either by implementing a plugin for JRebel or by adding a callback method which can be called by JRebel once a class is reloaded.

Could you please provide more details about your use case?

Comment: in our project we have xml files as supporting to application structure. we have .jar for the same. I had checked the rebel.xml so i want like if i do modification in XML then it will load all modified XML details

Comment: it means that XML files are the configuration files. Meaning that if you change the XML file then the application structure should change?